# Upgrading react native from 0.24 to 0.26

Tags: react-native

I used the method described here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Somehow I ended up on 0.27-rc1. Can someone prescribe a method to get off of the rc and on 0.26?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that never happen to me - (as described in that guide) you install explicit version react native

```
npm install --save react-native@0.26
```

so, I would suggest you to delete react native from `node_modules`, revert any changes you made with your source control system and start again by installing proper version of RN.